# passport local mongoose cookie not created

Tags: passport.js, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose

I'm new to web development. I have written a MERN app with React app running on localhost:3000 and backend running on localhost:5000. I'm authenticating using passport-local-mongoose. Auth works well but no cookie is created in the browser.

Any help appreciated. Here is my auth code:

```
passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info)
    {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Auth error: " + err); // FIXME
            res.json({success: false, message: err})
            return;
        }
        if (! user) {
            console.log("Username or password incorrect"); // FIXME
            res.json({success: false, message: 'Username or password incorrect'})
            return;
        }

        req.login(user, function(err)
        {
            if (err) {
                console.log("login error: " + err); // FIXME
                res.json({success: false, message: err})
                return;
            }

            // perform a deep copy of user
            const newUser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));

            // get user without salt and hash
            const {salt, hash, ...userNoSaltHash} = newUser

            res.json({success: true, message: "Authentication successful", user: userNoSaltHash});
        });
    })(req, res);
```

And here is my server.js

```
require('dotenv').config({path: './config/config.env'});
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db.js')
const errorHandler = require('./middleware/error.js');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const cors = require('cors');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// connect to mongoDB database
connectDB();

const app = express();

// setup CORS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNtFSVU-YTI
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    // FIXME methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    credentials: true,
}));

// FIXME do we need this?
app.use(express.static('public'));

// user body-parser get data JSON from body
app.use(express.json());

// FIXME read the docs and ensure these are what we want
app.use(session({
    //secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET, // FIXME
    secret: 'this is one jsaldfjklsfjklsdf f fjklsfj sjflsdfjdsjfdsf.',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    //cookie: {secure: true}
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/', require('./routes/auth'));

const User = require('./models/User.js')

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

// use static serialize and deserialize of model for passport session support
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// setup custom error handler; THIS SHOULD BE LAST PIECE OF MIDDLEWARE
app.use(errorHandler);

// middleware to print debug info
// app.get('/login', (req, res) =>
// {
//     console.log("Get: login");
//     res.send('Hello!')
// });

const server = app.listen(port, () => {console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`)});

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err, promise) =>
{
    console.log(`### Error: ${err}`);
    server.close(() => process.exit(1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are facing is creating the session and storing it even when the server restarts. I am not sure if my example will provide any guidance, but it works for me. I have used mongo store for storing the cookies even when the server restarts.
I am also new to this but hope it helps

**Here is my passport local startegy auth code**

```
const passport = require('passport');

const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const User = require('../models/user');

// authetication using passport
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'

},
    function(email,password, done){
        // find a user and establish the identity
        User.findOne({email: email}, function(err, user){
            if (err){
                console.log('error in finding user --> passport');
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user || user.password != password){
                console.log('Invalid username/password');
                return done(null, false);
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
)); 

// serializing the user to decide which key is to kept in the cookies
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
});


// deserializing the user from the key in the cookies
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    User.findById(id, function(err, user){
        if (err){
            console.log('error in finding user --> passport');
            return done(err);
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });
});

// check if the user is authenticated
passport.checkAuthentication = function(req,res,next){
    // if the user is signed in, then pass on the request to next function which is controller function
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    //  if the user is not signed in
    return res.redirect('/users/sign-in');
}

passport.setAuthenticatedUser = function(req,res,next){
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        // req.user contains the current signned in user from the session cookies and we are just sending this to the locals for the views
        res.locals.user = req.user
    }

    next();
}




module.exports = passport;
```

**Here is my server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const app = express();
const port= 8000;
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const db = require('./config/mongoose');
// used for session cookies
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const passportLocal = require('./config/passport-local-strategy');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');


// setting up sassMiddleware
app.use(sassMiddleware({
    src: './assets/scss',
    dest: './assets/css',
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
    prefix: '/css'
}));


app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());


//use assets folder for styling page
app.use(express.static('./assets'));

// using express layouts
app.use(expressLayouts);
//extract style and scripts from subpages into layouts
app.set('layout extractStyles', true);
app.set('layout extractScripts', true);

// set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './views');


// express-session setup mongo store is used to store the session coolkie in the db
app.use(session({
    name:  'codeial',
    // TODO to change the secret before deployment
    secret : 'blahsomething',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: (1000 * 60 * 100)
    },
    store: MongoStore.create(
        {
        mongoUrl: 'mongodb://localhost/codeal_devlopment',
        autoRemove: 'disabled'
     },
     function(err){
         console.log(err || 'connect-mongodb setup ok');
     }
    )
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(passport.setAuthenticatedUser);


// use express router
app.use('/', require('./routes/'));


// listening to the port
app.listen(port, function(err){

    // console.log('error ', err); 
    // we can write the same things as below known as interpolation
    if (err){
    console.log(`error while connecting to server: ${err}`);
    }
    console.log(`sucess, server running on the port: ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: My understanding is that with passport-local-mongoose, the cookie is auto created. I tested with a standalone app and the cookie was auto created. But when I break up the app info a client part (react app on localhost:3000) and a server part (localhost:5000) the cookie is not being created. In such a scenario, I don't understand how cookie creation works.

Comment: @YogiWannabe check out 'withCredentials' if you are hosting your app on two different domains (inc subdomains and ports).